# Eclipse Galileo Birt

Tags: eclipse-plugin

**While clicking on the Preview button or running the report in the web viewer Following ERROR is arising.**

> org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.RunFragment cannot be cast to org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.IFragment

Caused by:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.RunFragment cannot be cast to org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.IFragment
>       at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.layout.RunFragment_jsp._jspService(RunFragment_jsp.java:63)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:112)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:75)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:318)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:380)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:192)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.FramesetFragment.service(FramesetFragment.java:98)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet.__doGet(ViewerServlet.java:181)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doGet(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:160)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:59)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:318)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:380)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:535)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:865)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:540)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:213)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)

**What are the reasons behind it and its solutions**

Comment: everybody loves stacktraces ;)

Answer (score 0):

The two classes come from different classloaders. One is probably from OSGi, the other from the classloader of your app or your app container.

Try to print the values of `IFragment.class.getClassLoader()` and `RunFragment.class.getClassLoader()` to see if they are the same. If not, clean up your classloaders :-)

Check out [the FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Deployment) and [this (seemingly unrelated) FAQ item](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/JavaEventHandlers).