# Why am I getting this Exception on Eclipse-Indigo-Birt-Viewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, birt

I'm running my Eclipse Application with the Birt plugin. Every thing works fine, except for the preview. Clicking on preview leads to the following Exception (with any report):

I think the cause may be in the use of different Type of "Servlet". What should I do to debug/fix this?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.initializeDelegate(ServletManager.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:317)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:924)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: Can you add the code that is throwing the `ClassCastException`? Would be helpful.

Comment: this is the problem, the exception is not thrown by any of my code

Comment: Have you checked if you are upcasting a `ViewServlet` to a `Servlet`? Give a check to the answer in this post:[Classloader problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132186/eclipse-galileo-birt?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I'm not sure how. By intuition I just added the ***jetty*** plugin to my target-platform (dependencies). This was enough to fix this opaque exception. The Birt Preview is no fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Mars.2.
I observed that there are 2 javax.servlet plugins in my eclipse plugins-folder, after exiting eclipse, renaming the older one (3.0.0) to jar.x and starting eclipse again, the preview worked for me.